# Deklination von Adjektiven nach dem Wort "jener"

Tags: pronoun, declension, demonstrative-pronoun

Dies ist aus *Dem Untergeher* von Thomas Bernhard:

> Schon damals, also beinahe dreißig Jahre vor seinem Tod, hat Glenn
> keinen anderen Komponisten mehr geliebt als Bach, als zweiten Händel,
> Beethoven verachtete er, selbst Mozart war nicht **jener von mir wie
> kein anderer geliebter**, wenn *er* über ihn redete, dachte ich, als ich
> ins Gasthaus eintrat.

Meine Frage betrifft den fettgedruckten Teil. Wenn ich richtig verstehe (gar nicht garantiert), äußert der Icherzähler, dass Mozart wohl sein Lieblingskomponist ist, aber wenn Glenn über Mozart redet, ist dem irgendwie nicht mehr so. Oder so etwas Ähnliches. Muss in diesem Fall nicht am Ende "geliebte" statt "geliebter" stehen, um zum "jener" zu passen? Verkürzt wäre es doch "jener geliebte" oder vielleicht "jener Geliebte", oder? Wie es so im Buch steht, passt "geliebter" zum "kein", was mir komisch vorkommt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nach dem Artikelwort mit Endung *jener* wird schwache Flexion erwartet.

> jen**er** (von mir wie kein anderer) geliebt*e*
> ein (von mir wie kein anderer) geliebt**er**

Abweichungen wie das zitierte starke *geliebter* findet man immer wieder (wenn auch häufiger in die umgekehrte Richtung, also unerwartete schwache Flexion). Im vorliegenden Fall kann die Abweichung durch die große Distanz zum schwache Flexion auslösenden Artikelwort erklärt werden.

Bei [Suhrkamp](https://www.suhrkamp.de/buch/thomas-bernhard-werke-in-22-baenden-t-9783518415061) gibt es eine Leseprobe, in der wie erwartet *geliebte* steht. Man hat *geliebter* also als Fehler gewertet und korrigiert (wenn Bernhard tatsächlich so geschrieben haben oder dies einmal so gedruckt worden sein sollte).

Answer (score 0):

Meine Leseweise: der Schreiber (Bernhard) liebt Mozart wie keinen anderen, aber Glenn denkt/redet/kategorisiert ihn (=Mozart) viel minderwertiger. "geliebter" ist männlich, wie Mozart als Einzelperson, auf den sich das bezieht. Zum Vergleich die weibliche Variante: "..selbst die Queen war nicht jene von mir wie keine andere geliebte,...."

Answer (score 0):

Als Muttersprachler empfinde ich den Satz als grammatisch falsch. Wie der Fragesteller fühle ich mich durch die Form "geliebter" gedrängt, dieses Wort dem "kein anderer" zuzuordnen, was aber keinen Sinn ergibt. Es dem "jener" zuzuordnen wäre inhaltlich sinnvoll, dann müsste es aber "Geliebte" lauten.

Bei einem literarischen Werk wäre allerdings immer auch in Betracht zu ziehen, dass der Autor absichtlich von der grammatischen Konvention abweicht.

Comment: Die Zuordnung ist evtl. als Auslassung zu interpretieren: "selbst Mozart war nicht .. wie kein anderer geliebter Komponist"